# How to style product description output in sale.order report template in Flectra or Odoo?

Tags: odoo, qweb, flectra

I want to set the first line of the product description inside the printed PDF report of an Flectra/Odoo offer to BOLD so I added the following code to my model

```
@api.multi
def setFirstLineBold(self,txt):
    txt = txt.replace('\n', '<br/>')
    return txt

@api.multi
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    report = self.env['report']._get_report_from_name(self._template)  
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': self._ids,
        'doc_model': report.model,
        'docs': self.env['sale.order'].browse(self._ids),
        'setFirstLineBold': self.setFirstLineBold
    }

    return report_obj.render(self._template, docargs)
```

I then called the method inside my template

```
<t t-foreach="layout_category['lines']" t-as="l">
    <tr class="table-body">
        <span t-esc="doc.setFirstLineBold(l.name)"/></td>
```

But what happens then is actually exactly the opposite of what I want to achieve: The formatting that previously existed in the description text (the line breaks), which were previously shown with line breaks in the printed pdf-report, has been completely removed. The HTML-linebreaks `<br/>` are also printed instead of interpreted.

If I just run

```
@api.multi
def setFirstLineBold(self,txt):
    return txt
```

all linebreaks in the text (`'\n'`) seem to be removed or not interpreted, too. The text displays in one ugly block...

Now my question: How can I create formatting for the description text? I just want to make the first line bold.

thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RAW instead of ESC solves the problem:

```
<span t-raw="doc.setFirstLineBold(l.name)"/>
```

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/what-is-the-difference-between-t-esc-and-t-raw-92184